# tqdm slows down my program at a factor of at least 8

Tags: python, tqdm

To give a bit of context, I have a converter that request JSON data in two steps, one step 1 where it request the complete amount of Data_points and the second where per data point the details are requested. To keep track of the progress, because I am expecting to request a lot of data from this point. That is why I use tqdm, the problem it really is slowing my program done by at least a factor of 8.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import time
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import zipfile
import smtplib, ssl
from progress.bar import Bar
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
```

Here is the code:

```
def fetch_data_points(url: str):
    limit_request = 100
    # Placeholder for limit: please do not remove = 1000000000 -JJ
    folder_path_reset("api_request_jsons","csv","Geographic_information")
    total_start_time = start_time_measure()
    start_time = start_time_measure(
        'Starting Phase 1: First request from API: Data Points')

    for i in tqdm(range(limit_request)):
        response = requests.get(url,params={"limit": limit_request})
    API_status_report(response)
    end_time_measure(total_start_time, "Request completed: ")
    end_time_measure(total_start_time, "End of Phase 1, completed in: ")
    return response.json()
```

Keep note of the time here:

Here is the console working with tqdm.

```
Starting Phase 1: First request from API: Data Points
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:21<00:00,  4.69it/s]Successfull connection!

Request completed: 0:00:21.359000
End of Phase 1, completed in: 0:00:21.359000
Saving points
Exported_data\api_request_jsons\Fetch_points\Points.json saved
Point saved: 0:00:00.016000
Data saved. Total time of program run: 0:00:00.016000
Starting Phase 2: Second request from API: 100 requested
  9%|▉         | 9/100 [02:12<22:17, 14.69s/it]
```

And here is the console without tqdm:

```
Starting Phase 1: First request from API: Data Points
Successfull connection!
Request completed: 0:00:00.297000
End of Phase 1, completed in: 0:00:00.297000
Saving points
Exported_data\api_request_jsons\Fetch_points\Points.json saved
Point saved: 0:00:00.015000
Data saved. Total time of program run: 0:00:00.015000
Starting Phase 2: Second request from API: 100 requested
 10%|█         | 10/100 [01:54<16:52, 11.25s/it]
```

[image]

As you see here the program has slowed down by almost factor of ten. A request of 100 points takes normally 00.297000 seconds. But with TQDM that is 0:00:21.359000. More than five times slower than it should be. I would expect two times slower but five times its bit too much.. Can anyone give me some pointers to minimize this slow down as much as possible.

Edit: Okay I have decided to abandon this the tqdm measure on the first function, I just cannot get it done right. It takes too much tweaking and I have noticed that when I adjust the amount of data being requested the data is clearly inconsistent.

So I tried on the second function the code that is relevant is this:

To explain it request the details of each data-point and puts them into an array for later use:

```
def fetch_details_of_data_points(url: str):
    input_json = fetch_data_points(url)
    fetch_points_save(input_json)
    all_location_points_details = []
    amount_of_objects = len(input_json)
    total_start_time = start_time_measure()
    start_time = start_time_measure(f'Starting Phase 2: Second request from API: {str(amount_of_objects)} requested')
    for i in tqdm(range(amount_of_objects),miniters=1):
        for obj in input_json:
```

all_location_points_details.append(fetch_details(obj.get("detail")))

```
def fetch_details(url: str):
    response = requests.get(url)
    # Makes request call to get the data of detail
    # save_file(folder_path,GipodId,text2)
    # any other processe
    return response.json()
```

but I am getting an error here:

```
 Message=('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
  Source=C:\Users\xxxxxx\GIPOD_REQUEST_CONVERSION.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\QF6207\xxxxxx\GIPOD_REQUEST_CONVERSION.py", line 195, in fetch_details
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\GIPOD_REQUEST_CONVERSION.py", line 361, in fetch_details_of_data_points
    all_location_points_details.append(fetch_details(obj.get("detail")))
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\GIPOD_REQUEST_CONVERSION.py", line 446, in <module> (Current frame)
    fetch_details_of_data_points(api_response_url)
```

From what I can understand apparently the Request for one point datapoint just takes way too long causing the disconnect to happen.
Of note I know from experience that the request of one Datapoint it takes roughly 0.25 seconds for the data to be requested. So in theory the Progress bar should update and count up by one increment and update for every 0.25 seconds.

Now if this can be kind of be resolved by having the response time as the of the get command being the update time that would help a lot of making the progress bar a bit more accurate.

So how do I do this?

Edit: I have found a solution for my problem without actually doing much delay, after reading through I have found a creative way to the manual update after the function is done.

```
with tqdm (total=limit) as firstrequest:
    all_location_points_details = fetch_details_of_data_points(url,limit)
    firstrequest.update(limit)


with tqdm(total=amount_of_objects) as second_request:
    for obj in input_json: 
        all_location_points_details.append(fetch_details(obj.get("detail")))
        second_request.update(1)
```

Comment: Console I/O is inherently slow and tqdm does a _lot_ of it — so I suspect it's just a trade-off you're going to have to make. Updating less frequently is about the only option.

Comment: I am considering abondinging the TQDM measure for the first phase of my program. Because the thing is I have just noticed that for the first request the data is a lot in terms of time is really incositent however I might get it done for the second function (aka getting a request for each datapoint) but I get a connection problem error. Because of this I am gonna post an update.

Answer (score 5):

From the [tqdm docs](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#usage)

> miniters : int or float, optional
>
> Minimum progress display update interval, in iterations. If 0 and dynamic_miniters, will automatically adjust to equal mininterval (more
> CPU efficient, good for tight loops). If > 0, will skip display of
> specified number of iterations. Tweak this and mininterval to get very
> efficient loops. If your progress is erratic with both fast and slow
> iterations (network, skipping items, etc) you should set miniters=1

Reducing this parameter could speed things up.

Comment: Hmm I wil test this with as with miniter=0 and 1 because if this is correct, it shoudl solve my disconnection issue also.

Comment: I have tested it it really does need a lot of tweaking. Gonna be a bit hard to find out the min and maximum intervals for this.